# Finding Integers In a String java

Tags: java

I want to write a method called `printDigit` and that method should find how many integers are in a string.

For `15 an1234d 16 man` it should return `2`.

thats my hopeless code :)

```
public String printDigit() {
  String input = "15 an1234d 16 man";

  int len = input.split(" ").length;
  return len + "";
}
```

That returns `3`, it shouldn't count `an1234d` as an integer.

Comment: Look into regular expressions.

Comment: In particular, there's a class called `Matcher` which has the functionality that you need.  Look at the Javadocs for `Matcher` and also for `Pattern`.  Put a comment here if you still can't work it out after doing so.

Comment: Does it need to work for negative integers?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regular expression:

```
(^|\s)\d+(\s|$)
```

Which means: any number of digits, preceded by a space (or beginning of the string) and followed by a space (or the end of the string).

Here's a snippet demonstrating the use in Java. You can run a [**demo of this code online here**](http://ideone.com/q0438A).

```
public String printDigit() {
  String input = "15 an1234d 16 man";

  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(^|\\s)\\d+(\\s|$)");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
  int numberCount = 0;
  while(m.find()) {
      numberCount++;
  }

  return Integer.toString(numberCount);
}
```

Output:

```
Numbers: 2
```

---

### Update: per comments, an alternative using `parseInt()`:

Notice using `parseInt()` in this case is [*coding by Exception*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_by_exception) (which is considered a bad practice), but if you must use it, below is a snippet you can use. [**Run it online here**](http://ideone.com/PSIJFM).

```
public static String printDigit() {
  String input = "15 an1234d 16 man";
  String[] tokens = input.split(" ");
  int numberCount = 0;
  for(String s : tokens) {
      try {
          Integer.parseInt(s);
          numberCount++;
      } catch (Exception e) { /* couldnt parse as integer, do nothing */ }
  }

  return Integer.toString(numberCount);
}
```

Output:

```
Using parseInt(): 2
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it actually works but im tryin for using parseInt

Comment: Hmm, what do you mean by trying for using `parseInt()`? You need a solution that uses it?

Comment: I updated the answer with a snippet/demo that uses `Integer.parseInt()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method [`NumberUtils.isDigits(String str)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html#isDigits%28java.lang.String%29) from `org.apache.commons.lang.math.NumberUtils` .

> Checks whether the String contains only digit characters.

```
public String printDigit() {
  String input = "15 an1234d 16 man";
  int numb = 0;
  for(String str : input.split(" ")){
    if(NumberUtils.isDigits(str))
       numb++;
  }
  return Integer.toString(numb);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should verify every value in the Array if it NumberFormat

try to add that function :

```
String[] data= input.split(" ");
int k=0;

for(String str:data){
    try  
    {  
        double d = Double.parseDouble(str);  
        k++;
    }  
    catch(NumberFormatException nfe)  
    {  
        System.out.println("Not a number");
    }  
}
return k;
```

Comment: It's considered bad practice, from what I know, to check if a String is a number by attempting to parse and catching the exception. Exception handling adds overhead, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-regex solution (does not use `.split()`) that supports negative integers as well.  It works for all test cases such as `"-5 -3s0 1 s-2 -3-"`.

```
public int countInt(String s) {
    int count = 0;
    boolean isInt = false;
    boolean start = true;
    boolean neg;
    for (char n : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (start && Character.isDigit(n))
            isInt = true;
        neg = (n == '-') ? start : false;
        start = (n == ' ') ? true : neg;
        if (isInt && start)
            ++count;
        if (!Character.isDigit(n))
            isInt = false;
    }
    return count + (isInt ? 1 : 0);
}
```

It returns an int instead of a string:

```
> countInt("15 an1234d 16 man")
2
> countInt("-5 -3s0 1 s-2 -3-")
2
```